Why should not call super(ClassName, self).__init__() in derived class‘s construction function?
I've noticed that every example and doc and reference about backtrader never calls super(ClassName, self).__init__() in derived class, which is different from common use. For example, when I want to define a custom module in Pytorch, it would look like:
class MyModule(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModule, self).__init__()
        '''
            some logic
        '''

    '''
        other functions like forward(self)
    '''

But in backtrader, for example I define a custom Strategy, it looks like:
class MyStrategy(backtrader.Strategy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sma = backtrader.indicators.SimpleMovingAverage(period=15)


    '''
        other functions like start(self), next(self), prenext(self)
    '''

Why is that?

Why can we not call super(ClassName, self).__init__() in defining Class derived from backtrader's class? I know backtrader is based on metaclass programming, is it because of this? If so, how?
Can I or should I manually call super(ClassName, self).__init__() in derived class's __init__(self)  and why? If I shouldn't but I did, what consequences would be caused?

I have tried manually call super(ClassName, self).__init__() in derived class's __init__(self) but no consequences have been caused as far as I can tell, is it true?

Do you actually inherit any implementation worth invoking?

check backtrader.Strategy.__init__ - if it is empty or it doesn't exist then there is no need to use super(backtrader.Strategy, self).__init__() (or shorter super().__init__()) But usually classes have __init__() and nobody check if original class has __init__() but we simply use super().__init__(). Biesides if class needs super().__init__() and you don't use it then you may get error message from other functions. If you don't need super().__init__() but you use it then it should still work. So I would use super().__init__() in MyStrategy.__init__() automatically

here is source code backtrader.Strategy and it doesn't have def __init__() and it doesn't inherit from other class which would have def __init__() - so there is no need to execute super().__init__() in new class.
